# Excel VBA Variable Row reference in Formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am using VBA to apply the following formula into a Cell. I'd like to replace the reference to Cell `G11` with a `Long` that references the Row number of the ActiveCell. So instead of `G11` it would be `G55` if ActiveCell is on Row 55, or `G27` if ActiveCell is on is Row 27.

```
Columns("A").Find("", Cells(Rows.Count, "A")).Offset(-1, 7).Formula = "=IF(G11=""Enter date"",""Don't edit cell"",TEXT(G11, ""dddd""))"
```

I did try this but got Object Defined Error:

```
Dim ActiveRowNumber As Long
ActiveRowNumber = ActiveCell.RowNumber

Columns("A").Find("", Cells(Rows.Count, "A")).Offset(-1, 7).Formula = "=IF(G11=""Enter date"",""Don't edit cell"",TEXT(""G"" & ActiveRowNumber, ""dddd""))"
```

Comment: Hi, yes, updated code to show what I tried, but got Object Defined Error...

Comment: `range.formula = "=Sum(A1:A" & lastrow - 1 & ")"` is an example of using a variable in your inserted formula.  Note the position of the Quotations and the Ampersands.

Comment: I'm guessing you want R1C1 notation  Columns("A").Find("", Cells(Rows.Count, "A")).Offset(-1, 7).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-1]=""Enter date"",""Don't edit cell"",TEXT(RC[-1], ""dddd""))" so that the formula in H123 refers to the cell in G123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated your posted code:

```
Dim ActiveRowNumber As Long
ActiveRowNumber = ActiveCell.Row

Columns("A").Find("", Cells(Rows.Count, "A")).Offset(-1, 7).Formula = "=IF(G" & ActiveRowNumber & "=""Enter date"",""Don't edit cell"",TEXT(G" & ActiveRowNumber & ", ""dddd""))"
```

You left the `& "` out after the `ActiveRowNumber`.  The quotes around the `G` in `Text(""G""` appears to break you.